# LMC - How to increment an address?

Tags: little-man-computer

I am inputting several variables. I want to know how to increment the address each time, so each of the inputs are saved in a different address. I tried to ADD 1 everytime but it can only be for specific inputs, not for addresses.

Comment: Can you share your specific code so we can see what's going on?

Comment: duplicate of [How can I store an unknown number of inputs in different addresses in LMC (little-man-computer)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47346971)

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many inputs you will get, then just store each input in a predefined location (so: no loop).

If, on the other hand, the number of inputs is not known before hand, then you can use self-modifying code.

There are several ways to get a variable number of inputs. Here are some:

- Let the first input indicate how many inputs will follow
- Reserve a special value for indicating the end of the input, e.g. 0. This means that 0 cannot be part of the "real" inputs that come before this end marker.

Here is a program that stores the inputs at sequential memory locations until a 0 is input:

```html
#input: 1 2 3 0
LOOP   INP
       BRZ DONE
DYN    STA ARR
       LDA DYN  ; read the opcode
       ADD ONE
       STA DYN  ; modifying code!
       BRA LOOP
DONE   HLT

ONE    DAT 1
ARR    DAT    ; start of the array
       

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/trincot/lmc@v0.73/lmc.js"></script>
```

When you run this code, you'll notice that data is written beyond the `ARR` label. This happens because the instruction at `DYN` is updated dynamically in the loop. So in the second iteration it really is something like `STA ARR+1` -- although that is a syntax that is not supported.

In a real use case, you would do something with the collected data at label `DONE`, while here we just end the program.

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you need is the `DAT` function. This reserves a memory address that you can then `STA` (store) a variable in a specific memory address.

So for example: `A DAT` would reserve a memory address for variable `A`

Answer (score 0):

```
          INP
        STA N
LOOP    LDA A
        SUB N
        BRP ENDLOOP
        LDA A
        OUT
        LDA B
        ADD A
        STA ACC
        LDA B
        STA A
        LDA ACC
        STA B
        BRA LOOP
ENDLOOP HLT
A       DAT 0
B       DAT 1
N       DAT
ACC     DAT 1
```