# max/min of an unknown number of inputs in LMC?

Tags: assembly, little-man-computer

How can I print the maximum/minimum of an unknown number of inputs in LMC?

I know that I can SUB INPUT 1 FROM INPUT 2 and see if it is negative or positive but I don't know how to name the inputs so that I can load them.

PS: I found this useful link to help me with the ''unknown number of inputs" part
[How can I store an unknown number of inputs in different addresses in LMC (little-man-computer)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47346971/how-can-i-store-an-unknown-number-of-inputs-in-different-addresses-in-lmc-littl)

Comment: LMC doesn't have indirect memory addressing.  To loop over an array, you have to write self-modifying code.  But if you're reading inputs *from the user* one at a time, you don't have to store them in an array, just check if they're a new min or a new max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You link to code that stores an undetermined number of input values. But in your case that is not needed: you can keep track of the minimum and maximum while reading the input values. There is no need to actually *store* each input value:

```html
#input: 5 3 9 6 2 4
          INP ; data size
          STA count
          BRZ exit ; nothing to do
; initialise
          LDA zero
          STA max
          LDA big
          STA min
loop      LDA count
          SUB one
          BRP nextvalue
output    LDA min
          OUT
          LDA max
          OUT
exit      HLT

nextvalue STA count
          INP ; get data value
          STA value
          SUB min
          BRP checkmax
          LDA value
          STA min
checkmax  LDA max
          SUB value
          BRP loop
          LDA value
          STA max
          BRA loop

zero      DAT 0
one       DAT 1
big       DAT 999
count     DAT
min       DAT
max       DAT
value     DAT

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/trincot/lmc@v0.812/lmc.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can I also print the number of DATA  and all the inputs that the user enters without storing them?

Comment: Yes, but that is a different question. You would just do an `OUT` right after the second `INP`. So you immediately echo what is input. And then at the very end you also output the minimum and maximum.