# Programming arrays in LMC

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly, little-man-computer

I am working on this challenge:

> The program needs to accept a sequence of integers.  It ends with number 999.  The integers (except 999) are placed in a list.
> The integers must be less than or equal to 99.  Any inputs greater than 99 are not placed in the list.
>
> If the input would have more than ten numbers, only the first ten are stored.
>
> 999 is not part of the output.

I don't know how to limit the list length to ten (10) numbers. Also I don't know how to output the list in reverse order.

This is my code:

```
start   INP
        STA temp
        SUB big
        BRZ doout
        LDA temp
        SUB hundred
        BRP start
        sub one
        STA N
    
xx      STA ARR
        LDA xx
        add one
        sta xx
        BRA start
doout   HLT
temp    dat 0
big     dat 999
hundred dat 100
ARR     dat
one     dat 1
N       dat 10
```

Comment: Why would you need self-modifying code here?  `count` doesn't change in the loop, so it's 0 the whole time.  Or did you leave that out, and it's actually a duplicate of [How can I store an unknown number of inputs in different addresses in LMC (little-man-computer)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47346971)  I'm going to assume you meant `array[count++]` until you clarify, otherwise it's obviously trivial to just use the `array` label in your store instruction.

Comment: @PeterCordes In short, the integers are placed in a list limited to 10 integers and the list is then printed in reverse order.

Comment: Ok, then I guessed right at what you were *actually* trying to do.  That's not what your C code does, unless `input()` modifies a global `count`.

Comment: @PeterCordes you're a rockstar! thanks a ton.

Comment: @PeterCordes I edited my question to reflect the issues that I am having.

Comment: @julio11 There's still no question in your post.  What is your specific question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xx` in your program show that you haven't taken the hint from [How can I store an unknown number of inputs in different addresses in LMC (little-man-computer)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47346971)

It explains how you can have self-modifying code to walk through an array -- either to store values or to load them.

In your attempt there is no section that deals with outputting.

For the start section of the program I would actually suggest to subtract *first* the 100 and then 899 (which amounts to 999). That way you can keep the (reducing) input in the accumulator without having to restore it.

Also, due to an ambiguity in the specification of LMC, it is not entirely "safe" to do a `BRZ` right after a `SUB` (this is because the content of the accumulator is undefined/unspecified when there is underflow, so in theory it could be 0). You should always first do a `BRP` before doing a `BRZ` in the branched code. However, as input cannot be greater than 999, a `BRP` is enough to detect equality.

For the self modifying part, you can set an end-marker in your array data section, and define the `LDA` and `STA` instructions that would read/store a value at the *end* of the array. Whenever your code has that exact instruction, you know you have reached the end.

Here is how it can work:

```html
          LDA store # Initialise dynamic store instruction
          STA dyna1
loop      INP
dyna1     STA array
          SUB toobig
          BRP skip
          LDA dyna1
          ADD one
          STA dyna1
          SUB staend
          BRP print
          BRA loop

skip      SUB trailer
          BRP print # Safer to do BRP than BRZ
          BRA loop # Input was less than 999

print     LDA dyna1 # Convert dynamic store instruction
          SUB store # ... to index
          ADD load # ... to load instruction
          STA dyna2
loop2     LDA dyna2
          SUB one
          STA dyna2
          SUB load
          BRP dyna2
end       HLT # all done
dyna2     LDA array
          OUT
          BRA loop2


store     STA array
load      LDA array
staend    STA after
one       DAT 1
toobig    DAT 100
trailer   DAT 899
array     DAT
          DAT
          DAT
          DAT
          DAT
          DAT
          DAT
          DAT
          DAT
          DAT
after     DAT


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/trincot/lmc@v0.816/lmc.js"></script>
```

As you can see (while running the script here), the instructions at `dyna1` and `dyna2` are modified during the execution of the loop they are in.

Comment: I now see how the load and store instructions work. Thank you for your time.